# Why is my code not printing out the new balloon volume?

Tags: java, methods

I'm a beginner at Java and I'm having trouble understanding why my "Inflate" and "getVolume" methods aren't working. I'm sure they're just simple problems but I'd still like some help so I can fix my code and improve!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Balloon
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner multiplier = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How much should the radius be increased by? ");

        double amount = multiplier.nextDouble();

        double radius = 0;

        public void Inflate(double amount);
        {       
            double newRadius = radius + amount;
        }
        public double getVolume();
        {
            double sVolume = (4/3)*Math.PI*(newRadius*newRadius*newRadius);
            System.out.print(sVolume);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't declare a method in another method in java! You need to declare the method outside the main and remove the `;` after the method definition. You'll need to then call these methods after creating an object of the class.

Comment: I do not understand why the minuses in this question, at least has written the code and has asked politely.

Comment: @vmrvictor Thank you. I just started coding a little while ago and want some help.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that Ballon is an object you can inflate and has an state of radius, you can moreover get the volume.

The main method here is only to test if balloon works correctly

```
public class Balloon {

private double radius = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner multiplier = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("How much should the radius be increased by? ");

    Balloon balloon=new Balloon();
    double amount = multiplier.nextDouble();
    balloon.inflate(amount);
    double volume = balloon.getVolume();
    System.out.print(volume);
}

public void inflate(double amount) {
    radius = radius + amount;
}

public double getVolume() {
    double sVolume = (4 / 3) * Math.PI * (Math.pow(radius, 3));
    return sVolume;
}
}
```